# Call method only after prev method finish success

Tags: java, android, retrofit2

In my Android application I has my service that use retrofit

```
  static {
        myRestClient = RestClientFactory.createRestClient(TangoRestClient.class);
    }


    public static void getProfile(Callback<ApplicationProfileResponse> callback) {
        json.addProperty("locale", Locale.getDefault().toString().replace("_", "-"));
        Call<ApplicationProfileResponse> call = myRestClient.getAppProfile(json);
        // asynchronously
        call.enqueue(callback);
    }

    public static void method1(String email, String password, Callback<JsonElement> callback) {
        Call<JsonElement> call = myRestClient.login(email);
        call.enqueue(callback);
}

    public static void method2(String param, Callback<MyBanner> callback) {
        Call<MyBanner> call = myRestClient.method2(param);
        call.enqueue(callback);
}

...
    public static void methodN(String param, Callback<JsonElement> callback) {
        Call<JsonElement> call = myRestClient.method2(param);
        call.enqueue(callback);
    }
```

As you can see every method call asynchronously.
Nice.

But I need when call `method1`, `method2` ... or `methodN` to do the next :

Example:

Client call `method1()`

1. Call method `getProfile()`
2. After only after method `getProfile()` finish success then call `method1()`

Is it possible by **Retrofit 2**  ?

Comment: What you're looking for is called "chaining". Google it

Comment: One solution is to call the next method as part of your callback.

Comment: Is it possible do this by kotlin coroutine?